# Get type depending on what key i used on object

Tags: typescript

I have this type. "ERPTypes" can have multiple objects in it.

```
type ERPTypes = {
  'res.company': {
     account_enabled_tax_country_ids?: unknown
     account_fiscal_country_id?: false | [number, string]
     account_folder?: false | [number, string]
   }
}
```

I want to create an function that takes as param an "payload" where  "model" can only be the key of the Type "ERPTypes".

The problem i have is, i dont know how to get the keys of the `res.company` dynamically. I can harcode it like `(keyof ERPTypes['res.company'])[]`, this works. But the problem is i have alot of types and i dont want to hardcode it. How do i do this dynamically?

```
export type ReadPayloadT = {
  model: keyof ERPTypes
  ids: number[]
  fields?: (keyof ERPTypes['res.company'])[] // <---- This should be dynamically, it should depend of the key i use on "model"
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}
export const readQuery = (
  payload: ReadPayloadT
): Promise<ERPTypes[keyof ERPTypes][]> => {
  return axios
    .post(process.env['E_URL'] + '/api/v2/read', payload, {
      headers: {
        DATABASE: process.env['E_DB']!,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
}

readQuery({
  model: 'res.company',
  ids: [3],
  fields: ['account_fiscal_country_id'],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

```
export type ReadPayloadT<T extends keyof ERPTypes> = {
  model: T
  ids: number[]
  fields?: (keyof ERPTypes[T])[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}
export const readQuery = <T extends keyof ERPTypes>(
  payload: ReadPayloadT<T>
): Promise<ERPTypes[keyof ERPTypes][]> => {
  return axios
    .post(process.env['E_URL'] + '/api/v2/read', payload, {
      headers: {
        DATABASE: process.env['E_DB']!,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
}
readQuery({
  model: 'res.company',
  ids: [3],
  fields: [],
})
```

Now `fields` can only be the keys of the `res.company` only if i write `res.company` inside model.

Comment: You found a solution? It's identical to the one I posted before.

Answer (score 0):

You can make both `ReadPayloadT` and `readQuery` generic:

```
type ERPTypes = {
  'res.company': {
     account_enabled_tax_country_ids?: unknown
     account_fiscal_country_id?: false | [number, string]
     account_folder?: false | [number, string]
   }
}

export type ReadPayloadT<K extends keyof ERPTypes> = {
  model: K,
  ids: number[]
  fields?: (keyof ERPTypes[K])[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}

export const readQuery = <K extends keyof ERPTypes>(
  payload: ReadPayloadT<K>
): Promise<ERPTypes[keyof ERPTypes][]> => {
    // ... your implementation
}

readQuery({
  model: 'res.company',
  ids: [3],
  fields: ['account_fiscal_country_id'],
});
```